# Proper way to initialize a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I've noticed an interesting behavior of javascript when creating a dictionary.

```
class EventObject {
  constructor(event_number) {
    this.id = 'event_' + event_number;
    this.items = {};
  };
  ...
  ...
  
  addItem(item_type, seq, what, value) {
  ...  
  ...
  this.items[item_type][item_type + '_' + seq] = { what : value}; //this does not work as expected, the key will be "what" string instead of the value passed to the addItem function

  }

}
```

I found out that if I first create a dictionary it works as expected

```
this.items[item_type][item_type + '_' + seq] = {};
this.items[item_type][item_type + '_' + seq][what] = value;
```

Is this a feature of the javascript?

Comment: Should be `{ [what] : value }`

Comment: thank you Konrad, yes this works. Is it that necessary because the JS can't recognise the variable is a string?

Comment: Sometimes you want to create a key called `what`. There are two separate syntaxes so it won't mix

Comment: I get it, but I would use "what" : value in that case. It's an interesting feature of the language, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to learn more